# Getting dependencies error while installing ViZDoom

Tags: python, linux, cmake, dependencies

I am trying to install ViZDoom on Ubuntu system. I am following the steps given the following link https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom/blob/master/doc/Building.md.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Collecting vizdoom
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/6c/23565c09387173423883e7881fce53541ff89b5209ca0904c67e577dd6ac/vizdoom-1.1.7.tar.gz
Collecting numpy (from vizdoom)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/fc/4763e5f17ac6e7e7d55f377cde859ca1c5d5ac624441ab45315bc578aa9e/numpy-1.18.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: vizdoom
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for vizdoom ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-n60bvxmm/vizdoom/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpynt30bvbpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  CMake Warning:
    No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
    same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
    become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Looking for pthread.h
  -- Looking for pthread.h - found
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  -- Found Boost: /usr/include (found version "1.67.0") found components:  filesystem thread system date_time chrono regex iostreams atomic
  CMake Deprecation Warning at cmake_modules/CreateLaunchers.cmake:48 (cmake_policy):
    The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
    of CMake.

    The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
    policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
    specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
    behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    src/vizdoom/CMakeLists.txt:13 (include)


  -- Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR)
  -- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (found version "80")
  -- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11")
  -- Could NOT find GME (missing: GME_LIBRARIES GME_INCLUDE_DIR)
  -- Using system zlib
  -- Using system jpeg library
  -- Using internal bzip2 library
  -- Using internal gme library
  -- Performing Test HAVE_NO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
  -- Performing Test HAVE_NO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
  -- Performing Test __LIBGME_TEST_VISIBILITY
  -- Performing Test __LIBGME_TEST_VISIBILITY - Success
  -- Looking for strdup
  -- Looking for strdup - found
  -- Looking for strndup
  -- Looking for strndup - found
  -- Looking for sys/types.h
  -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
  -- Looking for stdint.h
  -- Looking for stdint.h - found
  -- Looking for stddef.h
  -- Looking for stddef.h - found
  -- Check size of char
  -- Check size of char - done
  -- Check size of short
  -- Check size of short - done
  -- Check size of int
  -- Check size of int - done
  -- Check size of long
  -- Check size of long - done
  -- /usr/include
  -- /tmp/pip-build-n60bvxmm/vizdoom/src/vizdoom/bzip2
  -- /tmp/pip-build-n60bvxmm/vizdoom/src/vizdoom/lzma/C
  -- Looking for itoa
  -- Looking for itoa - not found
  -- Performing Test DUMB_CAN_USE_SSE
  -- Performing Test DUMB_CAN_USE_SSE - Success
  -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")
  -- Checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
  --   No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
  CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
    Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_LIBRARY SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    cmake_modules/FindSDL2.cmake:179 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
    src/vizdoom/src/CMakeLists.txt:206 (find_package)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/tmp/pip-build-n60bvxmm/vizdoom/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/tmp/pip-build-n60bvxmm/vizdoom/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

  Installation failed, you may be missing some dependencies.
  Please check https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom/blob/master/doc/Building.md for details

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-n60bvxmm/vizdoom/setup.py", line 119, in <module>
      keywords=['vizdoom', 'doom', 'ai', 'deep learning', 'reinforcement learning', 'research']
    File "/home/rishabh29/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/rishabh29/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-n60bvxmm/vizdoom/setup.py", line 81, in run
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake'] + cmake_arg_list)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DBUILD_PYTHON=ON', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.6', '-DBUILD_PYTHON3=ON']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

When I try to install the ZDoom dependencies, I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-dev
E: Unable to locate package nasm
E: Unable to locate package libbz2-dev
E: Package 'libgtk2.0-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'cmake' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libfluidsynth-dev
E: Unable to locate package libgme-dev
E: Unable to locate package libopenal-dev
E: Unable to locate package timidity
E: Unable to locate package libwildmidi-dev
```

I think that there is CMake error or some version mismatch error but being new to it, I am unable to resolve it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The error message describes the problem. CMake cannot find some dependencies (bz2, sdl). The error message even says "*Installation failed, you may be missing some dependencies.*" Did you install all of the dependencies listed in the instructions you linked?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the dependency error as well. I have edited the question.

Comment: Did you try to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing the dependencies? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Yes, I did but it was showing the same error. I am using Ubuntu 18.10 cosmic

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is long gone ..... to the Ubuntu museum / old releases  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ , and is off topic on this site.

Comment: Yes, you should update your OS, or you will likely need to download and install many of these dependencies manually.